# Efficiently Reorganize or Reference Large Data in MATLAB

Tags: memory, matlab, data-structures, performance

I am currently bringing large (tens of GB) data files into Matlab using memmapfile.  The file I'm reading in is structured with several fields describing the data that follows it.  Here's an example of how my format might look:

```
m.format = { 'uint8' [1 1024] 'metadata'; ...
'uint8' [1 500000] 'mydata' };
m.repeat = 10000;
```

So, I end up with a structure m where one sample of the data is addressed like this:

```
single_element = m.data(745).mydata(26);
```

I want to think of this data as a matrix of, from the example, 10,000 x 500,000.  Indexing individual items in this way is not difficult though somewhat cumbersome.  My real problem arises when I want to access e.g. the 4th column of every row.  MATLAB will not allow the following:

```
single_column = m.data(:).mydata(4);
```

I could write a loop to slowly piece this whole thing into an actual matrix (I don't care about the metadata by the way), but for data this large it's hard to overemphasize how prohibitively slow that will be... not to mention the fact that it will double the memory required.  Any ideas?

Comment: do you know the size of your data before reading it?

Comment: Yes, I know everything about the format and size of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply map it to a matrix:

```
m.format = { 'uint8' [1024 500000] 'x' };
```

`m.Data(1).x` will be you data matrix.

Comment: This will not work since the metadata in the input file is interlaced with the sample data.  If the file goes [meta data block][sample data block][meta][sample][meta][sample], etc. I cannot just grab it all like that... unless you can think of a good way to separate out the metadata after the fact.  Can that be removed without copying the matrix?